# Why is fast sync not working with geth 1.1?

Tags: go-ethereum, clients, synchronization

When I run `geth --fast`

I get:

```
Incorrect Usage.

geth [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   1.1.0

[...]

flag provided but not defined: -fast
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update geth. Fast sync was implemented in version [1.3.1](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.1).