# Does installing geth download the entire blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

If I install geth, will it download the entire blockchain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell whether the Mist/Wallet is "fast" or "full" syncing?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/how-do-i-tell-whether-the-mist-wallet-is-fast-or-full-syncing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the synchronization mode you choose. From [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/11300/revisions):

- "Full" Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, and validate every element from genesis block.
- Fast Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, it performs no validation until current block - 1024. Then it gets a snap shot state, and goes like a full synchronisation.
- Light Sync: Gets only the current state. To verify elements, needs to ask to full (archive) nodes for the corresponding tree leave.

Answer (score 5):

No, installing geth does only install the binary go-ethereum client.

The blockchain only gets downloaded if you *run* geth. By default, the full blockchain gets downloaded if you just run `$ geth` without parameters. So, it's a 'yes' if that was your question.

You can control the behavior of the synchronization by adding the `--fast` or the `--light` flag as explained by Herman Junge.

Comment: So if I need to call web3.js API, which mode should be enough? Is the light mode enough?