# Geth determine synchronisation mode from console

Tags: go-ethereum

How can I get know using geth console was my database synced in fast or full mode ?

*UPD*
Its not the same as checking a process `ps ux | grep geth`. I know that i have started geth without sync parameter - i just to get know what a difference from client side on this state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell whether the Mist/Wallet is "fast" or "full" syncing?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/how-do-i-tell-whether-the-mist-wallet-is-fast-or-full-syncing)

Comment: UPD Its not the same as checking a process ps ux | grep geth. I know that i have started geth without sync parameter - i just to get know what a difference from client side on this state.

Comment: If you have started Geth _without_ the `--syncmode` parameter, then by default you are using `--syncmode=fast`, so you're doing a `fast` sync, not a `full` sync.

Comment: on Richard's comment, once your "fast" sync node catches up to the current block, it effectively switches to "full" sync. Also both "fast" and "full" syncs create "full nodes", but not "full archival nodes". For the latter you'll need to add `--gcmode=archive` and have 1.5TB+ of storage as of today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a :

```
  eth.getBalance('someaccount',some_block_number_very_back_into_the_past_like_block_1000000_or_so)`
```

if you get an error about the state entry, then you are in fast sync mode. To have a full node, you will need about 1 TB disk size, and your database will be storing every state change from block 0, so getting a balance of an account back into the past will not produce an error.

Comment: With new version of geth fast and full modes are more similar, both will drop 'old' states. Only a node run `--gcmode=archive` it will store all states, so it is possible for a node started as full to not return a balance for old blocks.