# Downloading full blockchain again after using geth --fast on 0.7.4

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization

I've downloaded the newest mist browser on a new pc and used `geth --fast`.

After fully syncing (which was about 1,5 hours) the syncing started from 0 again, but this time slow, downloading the whole chain. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I didn't delete the fast chain or anything.

Comment: Now did you confirmed that you synced full in first place ?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is expected.

The reason for using the `--fast` flag is to quickly get your node to the point where it's usable, and to do this initially only the block headers will by synced. You'll see messages of the following format (note "header(s)"):

```
I0416 13:35:53.497422   30629 blockchain.go:889] imported 192 header(s) 
  (0 ignored) in 71.941018ms. #6336 [2edbbc3f… / b80c9ac3…]
```

Once this preliminary sync of the headers is complete you'll see the following message:

```
I0416 17:16:12.631667   30629 blockchain.go:1251] imported 195 block(s) 
  (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 1.235990428s. #384 [d707e667 / d3d5d5c1]
I0416 17:16:12.631825   30629 sync.go:180] fast sync complete, auto disabling
I0416 17:16:48.831757   30629 blockchain.go:1251] imported 4 block(s) (0 
  queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 12.933585ms. #388 [bbb506ab / 0ace7268]
```

Geth will then start to sync the remaining block data (i.e. everything not in the block headers). You'll see messages of the following format (note "block(s)"):

```
I0416 13:32:23.331906   30581 blockchain.go:1251] imported 256 block(s) (0 
  queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 979.938402ms. #6366 [66dcf4c1 / c5d009a1]
```

[Explanation taken from the (much) longer answer, [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3060/52).]