# Ethereum redownloading entire blockchain after using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, clients, bug

[image]

As you can see from the image above Ethereum is redownloading the entire blockchain despite it being present in ".ethereum/chaindata".

This has happened after using Geth for the first time and updating the main client, unsure if one of these if any could be the problem, any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, tbh. Did you talk to the developers on github or gitter yet?

Comment: I haven't but I am certain it has something to do with running Geth on the same machine as a result of this post: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/downloading-full-blockchain-again-after-using-geth-fast-on-0-7-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears it had something to do with running Geth (go-ethereum) on the same machine, ended up deleting the "chaindata" folder and redownloading the blockchain.