# Geth synchronization

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

I downloaded geth and i've been waiting almost 3 days for the synchronization to finish. I've used the commands geth --fast --cache=512 --maxpeers 75 --jitvm. When geth is done downloading and syncing the blockchain does it show you a corresponding message or does it keep on downloading the new blocks? How do i know how much time left until it finishes?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/geth-node-starts-to-sync-from-the-beginning-after-fast-sync/3060#3060 for the messages you will see when `geth` is syncing normally, or fast. Fast syncing should take a few hours on a fast internet connection and a solid state disk. If you are not fast syncing, you may want to consider removing the old chaindata and then restarting the fast sync. After the full sync, it will continue receiving new blocks produced on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When geth log messages report a lot of blocks synced, it means node is not yet in-sync:

```
I0131 17:01:56.395603 core/blockchain.go:1042] imported 1560 blocks,  1610 txs (370.754 Mg) in    8.291s (44.715 Mg/s). #375988 [01c14ed2â¦ / 5fae052fâ¦]
I0131 17:02:26.547951 core/blockchain.go:1042] imported 1860 blocks,  1878 txs (359.007 Mg) in    8.042s (44.639 Mg/s). #382432 [b37e663eâ¦ / 43a0e456â¦]
```

but when they report just a few, it means it is synced:

```
I0206 13:20:32.849694 core/blockchain.go:1042] imported 1 blocks,     2 txs (  0.317 Mg) in  26.183ms (12.105 Mg/s). #483939 [7db3a92bâ¦]
I0206 13:20:45.187344 core/blockchain.go:1042] imported 1 blocks,     8 txs (  0.489 Mg) in  23.943ms (20.431 Mg/s). #483940 [32455099â¦]
I0206 13:20:58.534970 core/blockchain.go:1042] imported 1 blocks,     3 txs (  0.286 Mg) in  11.536ms (24.834 Mg/s). #483941 [6a6e35b4â¦]
```

Besides, you may check the block number at the end of the line. If it is the same as last block according to the blockchain browser ( https://testnet.etherscan.io/ ) , it mean your node is synced.

Comment: Thanks for your input. however the blocknumber is much greater than the last block on testnet.etherscan `I0206 15:45:32.254938 core/blockchain.go:1070] imported    1 blocks,     1 txs (  1.400 Mg) in 13m5.867s ( 0.002 Mg/s). #2325301 [88dae063…]` do you know why that is?

Comment: Maybe your node is syncing mainnet. https://etherscan.io/ Right now on block #3,133,876

Comment: how do I sync with the testnet through geth? do i have to delete all the mainnet db that has already downloaded?

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant but on the mist wallet i am up to date with the last block on the testnet

Comment: You may store two blockchains on disk, but geth node will sync just one of them: testnet or mainnet. They are stored on differente folders, so they don't interfere.

Comment: To sync testnet instead of mainnet, just add --testnet to the geth launch command